# How does the "Stable Fluids" algorithm by Jos Stam relate to the SIMPLE and PISO algorithms?

Tags: finite-difference, fluid-dynamics, finite-volume

The ["Stable Fluids"](https://05f43270-a325-4aeb-a1d8-39e42f0e9fcc.filesusr.com/ugd/cf1fd6_898fe9b63df946689101b8d074f8efba.pdf) paper **(*)** by [Jos Stam](https://www.josstam.com/publications) starts by acknowledging that *"Our method cannot be found in the computational fluids literature, since it is custom made for computer graphics applications. The model would not be accurate enough for most engineering applications."*

Nonetheless, it is based on the **Navier-Stokes** equations, solved in an Eulerian structured grid (well, with a semi-Lagrangian scheme for tracking properties that travel with the fluid).

When putting side-to-side his algorithm with the description of the SIMPLE/PISO algorithms as formulated in the CFD literature, I'm not able to find their common points or their differences.

I mean: can the algorithm by Jos Stam be understood as an approximation/modification of either SIMPLE or PISO? Or what should you modify in his algorithm so that it becomes SIMPLE/PISO?

Thanks a lot!

**(*) Note:** *The link to the paper in PDF format has been obtained from the official Jos Stam site, so I believe it is legit to put it here.*